# Shopify Version Porto Theme Ver 3.6.1, Need add to cart redirect to cart page with checkout option instead of staying on product page

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid-layout

I am not quite yet a full developer, but am working on a website that sells products.

The customer clicks a product

They see the product information, and after selecting a size, they click add to cart

After clicking add to cart, it notifies them that they added to cart with a quick splash saying (you've just added this to your cart) for a quick second, and then you have a choice of either going to cart, or continue shopping, but it quickly goes away.

We would like for it to just redirect from the product page, to the cart with the added product once they add it to their cart. How would I do this?

I tried going through some of the store code, but it is a bit over my head.

I tried asking chatgpt but they gave me a pretty broad way of how I would supposedly do it.

Going to ask Shopify next, but figured I'd ask the dev community to find a quicker fix.

All i need for it to do is just redirect to the customers cart once they've added it to the cart (and would love for that product to also simultaneously be in their cart as they are going to it if that was not obvious)

Website is here: https://southminisplits.com/

Comment: Figured I would give out the solution for anyone that needs it in the future.  

I had to remove the add-to-cart class from product_view_default.liquid Worked like a charm.

There are a lot of duplicate files that seem like the product file but you need to find the default one. Once you do that remove the class and it should be fine.